# How can I calculate the difference between two times that are in 24 hour format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In JavaScript, how can I calculate the difference between two times that are in 24 hour format?

Example: Get how many hours elapsed from `08:00:00` to `23:00:00`.

Below I'm getting two time values from two dropdown menus and trying to calculate the difference in hours between the two times. I get wrong results...

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VnwF7/1/

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function calculateTime() {
             //get values
        var valuestart = $("select[name='timestart']").val();
        var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

             //create date format       
        var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart);
        var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop);

        var difference = timeEnd - timeStart;            
        var diff_result = new Date(difference);    

        var hourDiff = diff_result.getHours();

        $("p").html("<b>Total Hours:</b> " + hourDiff )          
    }
    $("select").change(calculateTime);
    calculateTime();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="timestart">
<option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
<option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
<option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
<option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
<option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
<option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
<option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
<option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
<option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
<option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
<option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
<option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
<option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
<option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
<option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
<option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
<option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
<option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
<option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
<option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
<option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
<option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
<option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
</select>

<select name="timestop">
<option value="00:00:00">12:00 am</option>
<option value="01:00:00">1:00 am</option>
<option value="02:00:00">2:00 am</option>
<option value="03:00:00">3:00 am</option>
<option value="04:00:00">4:00 am</option>
<option value="05:00:00">5:00 am</option>
<option value="06:00:00">6:00 am</option>
<option value="07:00:00">7:00 am</option>
<option value="08:00:00">8:00 am</option>
<option value="09:00:00">9:00 am</option>
<option value="10:00:00">10:00 am</option>
<option value="11:00:00">11:00 am</option>
<option value="12:00:00">12:00 pm</option>
<option value="13:00:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="14:00:00">2:00 pm</option>
<option value="15:00:00">3:00 pm</option>
<option value="16:00:00">4:00 pm</option>
<option value="17:00:00">5:00 pm</option>
<option value="18:00:00">6:00 pm</option>
<option value="19:00:00">7:00 pm</option>
<option value="20:00:00">8:00 pm</option>
<option value="21:00:00">9:00 pm</option>
<option value="22:00:00">10:00 pm</option>
<option value="23:00:00">11:00 pm</option>
</select>

<p></p>
```

Comment: If possible go for JQuery Timepicker (checkout the datepair example) http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: every answer here only assumes the start time and the end time are in the same day - which is lot of times not the case - so **YOU'VE BEEN WARNED** :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can just subtract the hours right away doing it this way

```
var valuestart = $("select[name='timestart']").val();
var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

//create date format          
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();

var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;
```

Here's the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VnwF7/4/

UPDATE - to calculate if we are including the next day.  Just add the following if block

```
 if (hourDiff < 0) {
    hourDiff = 24 + hourDiff;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfvhqat9/

Comment: try to input 11:00 pm to 2:00 am it will give the difference -21.It is wrong

Comment: @MKPatel In that case you'd probably have to determine when to consider early/wee morning hours as the next day (this code sample assumes that both times are on the same day, and technically, 2 a.m. _is_ before 11 p.m.).

Comment: @RobertDundon `sample assumes that both times are on the same day` - exactly and that is wrong - time can only accumulate up to 23hours and 59minutes - so there is nothing to "consider" - it is clear that any end that is less that start is the next day.

Comment: wirey00 and if the start and stop is coming from the same select? I mean check the start and end of slots and hide the 1st option (asap)?

Comment: @MKPatel well, I guess this solution is for 24 hours format not for 12 hours, you are putting 11:00 pm which is 12 hours format.

Answer (score 11):

try this way

```
var time_start = new Date();
var time_end = new Date();
var value_start = "06:00:00".split(':');
var value_end = "23:00:00".split(':');

time_start.setHours(value_start[0], value_start[1], value_start[2], 0)
time_end.setHours(value_end[0], value_end[1], value_end[2], 0)

time_end - time_start // millisecond
```

Answer (score 9):

I changed your code to just use the difference without having to create another date object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
function calculateTime() {
        //get values
        var valuestart = $("select[name='timestart']").val();
        var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

         //create date format          
         var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart);
         var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop);

         var difference = timeEnd - timeStart;             

         difference = difference / 60 / 60 / 1000;


    $("p").html("<b>Hour Difference:</b> " + difference)             

}
$("select").change(calculateTime);
calculateTime();
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not Jquery but everything related to time and date in JavaScript...

This might help: datejs  http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

Here is some date and time calculation from the docs

```
 Date.today().set({ day: 15 })          // Sets the day to the 15th of the current month and year. Other object values include year|month|day|hour|minute|second.

        Date.today().set({ year: 2007, month: 1, day: 20 })


Date.today().add({ days: 2 })          // Adds 2 days to the Date. Other object values include year|month|day|hour|minute|second.

        Date.today().add({ years: -1, months: 6, hours: 3 })


Date.today().addYears(1)               // Add 1 year.
Date.today().addMonths(-2)             // Subtract 2 months.
Date.today().addWeeks(1)               // Add 1 week
Date.today().addHours(6)               // Add 6 hours.
Date.today().addMinutes(-30)           // Subtract 30 minutes
Date.today().addSeconds(15)            // Add 15 seconds.
Date.today().addMilliseconds(200)      // Add 200 milliseconds.

Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth()   // Returns the first day of the current month.
Date.today().moveToLastDayOfMonth()    // Returns the last day of the current month.

new Date().clearTime()                 // Sets the time to 00:00 (start of the day).
Date.today().setTimeToNow()            // Resets the time to the current time (now). The functional opposite of .clearTime()
```

EDIT:Since this is a rather old answer I lately do also use moment.js for date related operations really useful, too.
http://momentjs.com/
https://github.com/moment/moment/

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to convert them into dates for this specific case. Just Do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function calculateTime() { 
        var hourDiff = 
        parseInt($("select[name='timestart']").val().split(':')[0],10) -         
        parseInt($("select[name='timestop']").val().split(':')[0],10);

        $("p").html("<b>Hour Difference:</b> " + hourDiff )         
    }
    $("select").change(calculateTime);
    calculateTime();
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/dzAya/)​

Answer (score 2):

*This code works for me, Code is written by considering the AM PM difference. Just write the date based on your favorite format and try this code*

```js
function getTimeDifference(startTime, endTime) {
  const difference = endTime - startTime;
  const differenceInMinutes = difference / 1000 / 60;
  let hours = Math.floor(differenceInMinutes / 60);
  if (hours < 0) {
    hours = 24 + hours;
  }
  let minutes = Math.floor(differenceInMinutes % 60);
  if (minutes < 0) {
    minutes = 60 + minutes;
  }
  const hoursAndMinutes = hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
  return hoursAndMinutes;
}

const start = new Date(0,0,0,23,15);
const end = new Date(0,0,0,1,30);
const difference = getTimeDifference(start, end);
console.log(difference);
```