# How to calculate stopwatch/timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery/JavaScript timer that will continue running even when you've left the page.

I tried a few plugins to do this but in the end what I found worked best as a starting point was a jsfiddle I came across by the user Daniel_Hug:

http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pvk6p/

I've updated this to include Bootstrap 3, add some styles for responsive, and save the time of the timer into a cookie so it continues where it left off when you leave the page. Here's my updated version:

http://jsfiddle.net/ezrafree/hgks67u0/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="timeContainer" class="well well-sm">
                <time id="timerValue"></time>
            </div>
            <div id="timerButtons">
                <button id="start" class="btn btn-success">START</button>
                <button id="stop" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">STOP</button>
                <button id="reset" class="btn btn-default" disabled="disabled">RESET</button>
            </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
/**
 * jQuery Stopwatch
 * by @websightdesigns
 *
 * Based on "Javascript Stopwatch" by Daniel Hug
 * From http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pvk6p/
 * Modified to:
 * - add responsive css styles
 * - add save functionality with cookies
 */

// Initialize our variables
var timerDiv = document.getElementById('timerValue'),
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'),
    t;

// Get time from cookie
var cookieTime = getCookie('time');

// If timer value is saved in the cookie
if( cookieTime != null && cookieTime != '00:00:00' ) {
    var savedCookie = cookieTime;
    var initialSegments = savedCookie.split('|');
    var savedTimer = initialSegments[0];
    var timerSegments = savedTimer.split(':');
    var seconds = parseInt(timerSegments[2]),
        minutes = parseInt(timerSegments[1]),
        hours = parseInt(timerSegments[0]);
    timer();
    document.getElementById('timerValue').textContent = savedTimer;
    $('#stop').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#reset').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0;
    timerDiv.textContent = "00:00:00";
}

// New Date object for the expire time
var curdate = new Date();
var exp = new Date();

// Set the expire time
exp.setTime(exp + 2592000000);

function add() {

    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    timerDiv.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00")
        + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00")
        + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    // Set a 'time' cookie with the current timer time and expire time object.
    var timerTime = timerDiv.textContent.replace("%3A", ":");
    // console.log('timerTime', timerTime);
    setCookie('time', timerTime + '|' + curdate, exp);

    timer();
}

function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}

// timer(); // autostart timer

/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
reset.onclick = function() {
    timerDiv.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
    setCookie('time', "00:00:00", exp);
}

/**
 * Javascript Stopwatch: Button Functionality
 * by @websightdesigns
 */

$('#start').on('click', function() {
    $('#stop').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#reset').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#stop').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});

/**
 * Javascript Stopwatch: Cookie Functionality
 * by @websightdesigns
 */

function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cname = name + "=";
    var dc = document.cookie;

    if (dc.length > 0) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(cname);
        if (begin != -1) {
        begin += cname.length;
        end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
            if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
            return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * TODO: Continue timing the timer while the browser window is closed...
 */
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * jQuery Stopwatch
 * by @websightdesigns
 */

#timeContainer,
#timerButtons {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#timeContainer {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

#timerValue {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#timerButtons {
    text-align: center;
}

#timerButtons button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #timeContainer,
    #timerButtons {
        width: 210px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #timeContainer {
        width: 184px;
    }
    #timerButtons button {
        max-width: 32.75%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 240px) {
    #timeContainer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #timerButtons button {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    }
}
/**
 * jQuery Stopwatch
 * by @websightdesigns
 */

#timeContainer,
#timerButtons {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#timeContainer {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

#timerValue {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#timerButtons {
    text-align: center;
}

#timerButtons button {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #timeContainer,
    #timerButtons {
        width: 210px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #timeContainer {
        width: 184px;
    }
    #timerButtons button {
        max-width: 32.75%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 240px) {
    #timeContainer {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #timerButtons button {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm saving my cookie with a value such as:

```
00:02:28|Mon Mar 16 2015 10:29:42 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

In the above example, `00:02:28` is the current time of the timer, and the `Mon Mar 16 2015 10:29:42 GMT-0600 (MDT)` is the current date. What would be the best way to calculate what the new value of the timer would be if it had been running still while the window/tab was closed?

Comment: Your javascript won't run anymore when you close the window/tab where is running.

Comment: If I were doing this I would set the cookie as the time the timer was started.  Then you could just get the difference like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038252/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-that-are-in-24-hour-format).  The way you are doing it, you would do the same, but then would have to add the existing stopwatch time back in

Comment: store start `timestamp` in `localStorage`.and compare it with current time to get timer.

Comment: @Jacob is suggesting the way I'd also do it, you can convert two dates/times to milliseconds very easily, subtract one from the other, and use that value to set the new timer. Converting your original `XX:XX:XX` timer value to milliseconds as well and adding it in seems like an unnecessary step

Answer (score 1):

This could probably do with some refining, but in your code that runs when a cookie is found:

```
var date = new Date(initialSegments[1]);
date.setHours(date.getHours() + parseInt(timerSegments[0],10), date.getMinutes() + parseInt(timerSegments[1],10), date.getSeconds() + parseInt(timerSegments[2],10));    
var secsDiff = ((date - new Date(initialSegments[1]))/1000);
var seconds = secsDiff%60,
    minutes = Math.floor(secsDiff/60),
    hours = Math.floor(secsDiff/(60*60));
add();
```

What this does is gets the time from the cookie, and adds on the last timer time which was also saved to the cookie. It then works out how much time has elapsed and adds that one.

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/hgks67u0/1/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a complete solution, I took @Jamiec's solution and built on top a multiple timer which works when you close the window, switch tabs or navigate off the page. Might point someone in the right direction.

The key difference is I had to add this bit of logic to @Jamiec's solution.

```
var savedCookie = cookieTime,
    initialSegments = savedCookie.split('|'),
    savedTimer = initialSegments[0],
    timerSegments = savedTimer.split(':'),
    date = new Date(initialSegments[1]);

var currentTimeDifference = Math.round((new Date() - date)/1000);
if (localStorage[elements[index].timerName + '_started'] == 'true') {
    date.setHours(
        date.getHours() + parseInt(currentTimeDifference / (60 * 60), 10),
        date.getMinutes() + parseInt(Math.floor(currentTimeDifference / 60), 10),
        date.getSeconds() + parseInt(currentTimeDifference % 60, 10)
    );
}

date.setHours(
    date.getHours() + parseInt(timerSegments[0], 10),
    date.getMinutes() + parseInt(timerSegments[1], 10),
    date.getSeconds() + parseInt(timerSegments[2], 10)
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/asherkhan111/ogvyd1xv/2/