# How to calculate difference between two timestamps using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two timestamps and I need difference between them in hours. How to calculate them.

```js
var resolution
var EndTime = 1541092163000
var StartTime = 1541077763000
resolution = slaEndTime - slaStartTime
var resolutionTime = ((resolution / (1000 * 60)) % 60)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `sla` prefix is an issue with copying your code to SO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two times that are in 24 hour format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038252/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-that-are-in-24-hour-format)

Comment: That's not a duplicate... the time here is not in 24 hour format

Comment: First convert both to same time format, may be to IST, then convert to milliseconds and find the difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to divide  rather than do times and modulus

`/1000` will convert it to seconds

the first `/60` will convert to minutes

and the last `/60` hours

```js
var resolution
var EndTime = 1541092163000
var StartTime = 1541077763000
resolution = EndTime - StartTime
var resolutionTime = (((resolution / 1000) / 60)/ 60)
console.log(resolutionTime)
```

Or you can use momentjs https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

See the snippet below.
You need to divide by 1000 then by 60 and then by 60 again to get the hours.
In short you need do divide by 1000*60*60=3600000.

```js
var endTime = 1541092163000;
var startTime = 1541077763000;
var differenceInMiliseconds = endTime - startTime;
var differenceInSeconds = differenceInMiliseconds / 1000;
var differenceInMinutes = differenceInSeconds / 60;
var differenceInHours = differenceInMinutes / 60;
console.log(differenceInHours);

// or in short
console.log((endTime - startTime) / 3600000);
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do this ?

```js
var resolution
var EndTime = 1541092163000
var StartTime = 1541077763000
var resolution = EndTime - StartTime
var resolutionTime = (parseFloat(resolution) / (60000*60) ) 
console.log(resolutionTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself from manual dates manipulation insanity and use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/)

```
const moment = require('moment');

var EndTime = 1541092163000
var StartTime = 1541077763000
var resolution = moment(EndTime - StartTime).asHours();
```

Comment: Sure, add a 50 kB library to substract two numbers from each other. Might be a bit of an overkill

Comment: Sure it is the right way! Initially I wanted to suggest jQuery because of https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif, but then realized it's kinda felt out of fashion

Answer (score 0):

This approach helped to get a basic hours, minutes, seconds breakdown.

```js
const Duration = (difference) => {
    let secondsInMiliseconds    = 1000, 
        minutesInMiliseconds    = 60 * secondsInMiliseconds,
        hoursInMiliseconds      = 60 * minutesInMiliseconds;

    var differenceInHours       = difference / hoursInMiliseconds,
         differenceInMinutes    = differenceInHours     % 1 * 60,
         differenceInSeconds    = differenceInMinutes   % 1 * 60;
    return {
        "hours"   : Math.floor(differenceInHours),
        "minutes" : Math.floor(differenceInMinutes),
        "seconds" : Math.floor(differenceInSeconds)
    }
}
let aLittleWhileAgo = (new Date()-10000000)
let now = new Date();
console.log(Duration(now-aLittleWhileAgo))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ms to calculate the difference between two timestamps

```js
const ms = require('ms');

var EndTime = 1541092163000;
var StartTime = 1541077763000;

ms( EndTime - StartTime) //return 4h
```

Comment: Can you include what ms is?

Comment: How this will help? No explanation and what is `ms`? This could be easily achieved by simple JS. No need for third party package. George provided solution for it.

Comment: ms is a popular NodeJs framework that transform between various time formats and milliseconds.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms

Comment: The last comment should be inside the answer.