# Get the total duration in minutes from 2 fields showing the time in 24 format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code. I'm trying to get the the total duration in minutes and display it in the 3rd field.

```
13:00  14:10  01:10
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#time').ready(function() {
    var time = new Date();
    $('#time-holder').val(time.toTimeString().slice(0, 5));
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#time2').ready(function() {
    var time = new Date();
    $('#time-holder2').val(time.toTimeString().slice(0, 5));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder2">
<input type="text" value="" id="total">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/patrolcad/Lf0ky784/4/

Comment: The ready event is meant to be used for the document, not child elements.  Your ready logic doesn't make sense, especially given that they are nested within other ready methods.  `$(function(){})` is a ready handler

Comment: Also the example output seems wrong. `13:00` to `14:10` would be `1:10`...? Finally, regarding tags, this has nothing to do with PHP and jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation framework. To calculate differences between dates you need plain old JS. I've updated the tags for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two times that are in 24 hour format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038252/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-that-are-in-24-hour-format)

Comment: Ok, you've given us some setup.  Where's your attempt to actually solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

It might be easiest to split the numbers by the colon and then `h * 60 + m`