# Face NaN result when calculating time difference with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie and still at the beginner level of PHP, Javascript, Codeigniter. I'm facing an unexpected result when I try to calculate the time difference between two 12 hours format time inputs.

Here is the **HTML,JS**

```js
 function hitungjam() {
        var start = new Date($('#inputJammulai'));
        var end = new Date($('#inputJamselesai'));
        var s = start.toTimeString();
        var e = end.toTimeString();
        var diff = e - s;
        var jam = Math.floor(diff/1000/60/60);
        $('#inputSelisih').val(jam);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="inputJammulai">Start</label>
      <!-- <div class="form-label-group"> -->
        <input type="time" name="inputJammulai" id="inputJammulai" class="form-control" required="required">
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="inputJamselesai">End</label>
      <!-- <div class="form-label-group"> -->
        <input type="time" name="inputJamselesai" id="inputJamselesai" onchange="javascript: hitungjam();" class="form-control" required="required">
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT**
[image]

start 09:00 AM 
end 11:30 AM 
the result is `NaN`.

**WHAT EXPECTED RESULT**
start at 09:00 AM, end at 11:30 AM, the result is 2,5

Oh FYI, before I write down this question I've done a search and tried many solutions given from StackOverflow but doesn't work on my problem. That's why I'm asking now.
Can anyone here help me to find out the solution? Thank you

Comment: `var start = new Date($('#inputJammulai').val()), end = new Date($('#inputJamselesai').val());` currently you're trying to convert jquery objects into Dates.

Comment: don't subtract from `toTimeString()` .subtract from date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038252/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-that-are-in-24-hour-format

I think you may try to refer example here

Comment: @Thomas thank you for your tips, but it still doesn't work on my project

Comment: @Xun yeah thanks for the alternative calculation method, I'll try it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some modifications to your original code so you can get a **base** working example, I will try to explain some of these:

- 1) You was not getting the values from your inputs, you need to use `.val()` for this.
- 2) You can't make a difference between strings and expect a number as result. Instead of this, I have splited the obtained values from the inputs into `hours` and `minutes`. Then we create new `Date` objects with current time and set the respective `hours` and `minutes` to they. Finally, we can use difference within the `Date.getTime()` of each `Date`.
- 3) `Math.floor()` will return an integer, but you want a number with decimals, so instead of this I use `toFixed(1)` to get a decimal number (as string) with one digit after the `dot`.

**Base Example:**

```js
function hitungjam()
{
    var [h1, m1] = $('#inputJammulai').val().split(":");
    var [h2, m2] = $('#inputJamselesai').val().split(":");
    var start = new Date(), end = new Date();
    start.setHours(h1);
    start.setMinutes(m1);
    end.setHours(h2);
    end.setMinutes(m2);    

    var diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var jam = (diff / 1000.0 / 60 / 60).toFixed(1);
    $('#inputSelisih').val(jam);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" name="inputJammulai" id="inputJammulai" class="form-control" required="required">
<input type="time" name="inputJamselesai" id="inputJamselesai" onchange="javascript: hitungjam();" class="form-control" required="required">
<label>Difference (hours):<label>
<input type="text" id="inputSelisih">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I'm looking and it works. Thanks too for your explanation. But can I ask about the `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, is that okay if I'm not download and put it to my local project, I'm just mentioning it on the body?

Comment: @eleonoraanggi That is the `JQuery` library from a `CDN`. I assume you should have it on you local environment (maybe not the same version) or the code you provided originally will not work. You can ignore that, it is just included for the example to work because it uses `JQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is couple of things First in order to get the value from the input use `val()` which was missing. Secondly the output from the `input` is a string, so use `parseInt` to convert it to number before doing mathematical operations

Using `split` to get the numbers from the input since the input will be like `9:00` for `9:00AM` or `23:30` for `11:30PM`.

```js
function hitungjam() {
  var start = $('#inputJammulai').val();
  var end = $('#inputJamselesai').val();
  let diff = toMins(end) - toMins(start);
  let jam = `${Math.floor(diff/60)}:${diff%60}`;
  $('#inputSelisih').val(jam);
}


function toMins(time) {
  let splitTime = time.split(":");
  return (parseInt(splitTime[0], 10) * 60) + parseInt(splitTime[1], 10)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="inputJammulai">Start</label>
      <!-- <div class="form-label-group"> -->
      <input type="time" name="inputJammulai" id="inputJammulai" class="form-control" required="required">
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="inputJamselesai">End</label>
      <!-- <div class="form-label-group"> -->
      <input type="time" name="inputJamselesai" id="inputJamselesai" onchange="javascript: hitungjam();" class="form-control" required="required">
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input id='inputSelisih'>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works and now I know where it's missing.