# Getting difference between two times in twenty four hour format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time

I have a dropdown with starting and ending time of tuition classes.The format of the time is in 24 hours.
eg-

```
08:30 - 12:00
21:00 - 00:00
05:00 - 10:00
```

I need to get the difference between start and end time in hours. And I used the following code.

```
var diff = parseFloat(endTime) - parseFloat(startTime);
```

So if I select the time 21:00 - 00:00, this gives the output as -21. But actual value should be 3 hours.Furthermore if somebody select a time as 21:00 - 00:00 the difference should be 3 hours while if somebody select a time of 21:00 - 12:00 the difference should be 15 hours. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two times that are in 24 hour format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038252/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-that-are-in-24-hour-format)

Comment: Although its the same question, the given answer doesn't provide the correct answer for some scenarios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First solution :** Convert your hour in **DateTime** format and use

```
function diff_hours(dt2, dt1) 
 {

  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= (60 * 60);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));

 }
```

This will give you the diff in hours.

**Second solution :** custom function if you really want to use only string.

```
function diffTime(time1,time2) {
    var hour1 = time1.split(':')[0];
    var hour2 = time2.split(':')[0];
    var min1 = time1.split(':')[1];
    var min2 = time2.split(':')[1];

    var diff_hour = hour2 - hour1;
    var diff_min = min2 - min1;
    if (diff_hour<0) {
        diff_hour+= 24;
    }
    if (diff_min<0) {
        diff_min+=60;
        diff_hour--;
    } else if(diff_min>=60){
        diff_min-=60;
        diff_hour++;
    }
    return [diff_hour,diff_min]

}
```

Comment: To convert my time to Date Time format I need a date right?

Comment: Yes of course, or you can use `var currentDate = new Date();` and change the hour after if you don't care about day. But your problem is that you need to clarify what "0:00" mean. Start of your day ? end of your day ?

Comment: 00:00 would be the start of the day

Comment: so if you want only positive differences, seems like the second solution can do the job

Comment: But It doesn't give the correct answer if I choose 21:00 - 00:00. It provides 21:00 but actual value should be 3h

Comment: I made a mistake and invert hours and minutes! It's correct now :)